# Firebase -Node.js auto complete doesn't show .auth() or it's accompanying methods

Tags: node.js, firebase, module, autocomplete, firebase-admin

I'm running **Node version 7.8.0**

I have installed the **Firebase** and **Firebase-admin** modules into a Server side Node.js **app.js** file. I want to use these 2 methods:

```
var myCustomToken = '12345'

firebaseAdmin.auth().createCustomToken(myCustomToken) //firebaseAdmin.auth()

firebase.auth().authenticateWithCustomToken(myCustomToken) // firebase.auth()
```

The problem is dot `.auth()` doesn't show up for either module so I can't get to use the 2 methods. There are other methods that are tied to both modules that appear (in pics below) but `.auth()` isn't one of them.

For e.g.

```
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(... //works
firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(... //works

firebase.initializeApp(...) //works
```

These are the modules I installed in the folder that was initialized with **npm**:

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
npm install algoliasearch --save
npm install firebase --save
```

These are the dependencies inside my **package.json** file:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^3.22.1",
    "firebase": "^3.7.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.1.4"
  }
```

**How can I get .auth() to appear on each module so I can access the 2 methods I need?**

**Firebase-admin module autocomplete:**

[image]

**Firebase module autocomplete:**

[image]

**Autocomplete results for both modules .auth() doesn't exist:**

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues) on the GitHub repo to get this investigated.

Comment: @Michael Bleigh thanks for the help. Earlier today I sent a copy of this to firebase tech support. Hopefully they get back to me soon. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed an issue report at the [Firebase-admin github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/211)  and they got back to me and said that even though the `.aut()` object isn’t showing up in Sublime’s autocomplete it does exist. Since I knew the methods I was looking they said I could just manually put in the code and it would work which in fact it did.

One thing they suggested was that next time I can go into the `node_modules` folder and I would see that it does exist there:

```
node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js
```

this is what is there:

```
Object.defineProperty(FirebaseNamespace.prototype, "auth", {
        /**
         * Gets the `Auth` service namespace. The returned namespace can be used to get the
         * `Auth` service for the default app or an explicitly specified app.
         */
        get: function () {
            var _this = this;
            var fn = function (app) {
                return _this.ensureApp(app).auth();
            };
            return Object.assign(fn, { Auth: auth_1.Auth });
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
```

Basically if your using Sublime and autocomplete isn’t showing what your looking for just manually type it in and look through the `node_modules` folder to verify it’s there.

Another alternative is to use VSCode or Vim instead of Sublime and the autocomplete should work there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk

for `createCustomToken()`

As for the client part, did you try `signInWithCustomToken()` ?

Comment: hey thanks. I came across that before but the problem of not accessing the .auth() object was still the deterrence. It says the method is on the .auth() object and not getting access to it is the main problem. Thanks though!